# Access docker on WSL2 from Windows CLI

Tags: docker, wsl-2

My Windows machine runs docker on a Linux distribution via WSL2. That way I can only access the docker CLI through a shell on WSL. I would like to have the `docker` command available on Windows directly. How can I install a docker-cli-client on windows that connects to the docker daemon on WSL?

I know that when I install [Rancher Desktop](https://docs.rancherdesktop.io/) a `docker`-binary gets added to the Path that does exactly what I want. Is there a way to get this functionality standalone, without having to fully install Rancher Desktop? Rancher Desktop adds its own WSL distribution and runs Docker on that, but I want to set this up myself with a distribution of my choice.